# convert < and > to &lt; and &gt; in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, tags

i have this string

```
<PARAMETERS zone = "6" check_in = "2012-07-01" check_out = "2012-07-02">
            <ROOMS>
               <ROOM adults = "2" children = "0"/>
            </ROOMS>
        </PARAMETERS>
```

And i want to obtain this other in vb.net

```
&lt;PARAMETERS zone = "6" check_in = "2012-07-01" check_out = "2012-07-02"&gt;
        &lt;ROOMS&gt;
            &lt;ROOM adults = "2" children = "0"/&gt;
        &lt;/ROOMS&gt;
    &lt;/PARAMETERS&gt;
```

Someone knows if exists a function to do it directly?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the context here? If you're doing things with XML, you should usually avoid doing any direct string manipulation - use XML APIs instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx) will do the trick.

From MSDN:

> Converts a string into an HTML-encoded string.

One overload can be used like this:

```
var html = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myStringToEncode);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to replace specific characters you can also use the [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method

```
mystr.Replace("<", "&lt;");
```

Comment: The replace don't work for me for this two specific characters! Thanks.